# How To File Sharing From PC To Remix OS on VM-ware Player?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, android-emulator, file-sharing, vmware, remix-os

I have a problem, I have installed my Remix OS on my VM-ware Player and I would like to transfer file between PC and Remix OS.

how do file sharing between my PC and my Remix OS? Because it cannot just simply copy and paste. Please help me out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set up one or more shared folders for a virtual machine, be sure the virtual machine is open in Workstation and click its tab to make it the active virtual machine. Choose VM > Settings > Options and click Shared folders.

[image]

You can add one or more directories to the list. Those directories may be on the host computer or they may be network directories accessible from the host computer. All the files copied to that folder will be accessible in both guest (remixOS) and host (Windows) machines

Credits

[Shared folders setup](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/ws_running_shared_folders.html)